# Bootstrap containers stacking in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this is a simple one for someone. Open the site below in IE7/8, Chrome, FF.  It displays fine in the latter two, but things stack up in IE, widths don't take effect and IE seems to ignore the Bootstrap container (specifically the margins and centralisation). I have added Respond.js which helped a tiny bit.

http://danielcooper.github.io/radarsite/bootstrap/jenny.html

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IE7/8 doesn't know about HTML5 or media queries witch bootstrap uses. So you'll need to use a javascript library called Modernizr, and also keep that Respond.js. You can find it here: http://modernizr.com/

Don't forget to add a conditional comment for browser below IE9 in your header, like so:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Lib/Html5/modernizr.custom.50229.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Lib/Html5/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

LE: Do know: the new Bootsrap 3 RC1 doesn't offer support any more for IE7